# MuleSoft - TCP Connector - reconnect forever, when to configure?

Tags: tcp, mule, mule-component

I am using TCP connector which is connecting to a different system using a custom class developed in java. In TCP connector I have enabled "Send TCP No Delay", "Reuse Address", "Keep Send Socket Open" and "Keep Alive".

[image: Screenshot of the Global Element Properties]

I have also configured Reconnection forever every 10 secs.

Whole day it works fine but when the other system reboots everyday midnight, mule starts showing connection problem and it's unable to connect until I restart the mule server. Rebooting the other system takes less than 3 minutes.

I am not sure how the reconnection works and how all those Keep Alive, Reuse Address and other TCP settings work in the TCP connector.

Any one can help me with a solution to keep the system connected even it restarts or available after a certain period.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant part of your flow XML? Thank you very much.

Comment: Also the Mule version and post your custom Java class. It is not clear if the problem is in there.